# Ondragstart Attribute doesn't appear when created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have my images in an array and I have to create a div with an image inside dynamically and that image has to had the ondragstart attribute but I can't make it work. I used everything.

```
function showOptions(i,j){
var div= document.createElement("div");
var img = document.createElement("img");
var divOptions= document.getElementById('options');

div.id = "div"+i+j;
img.src = imgArray[i][j].src;
div.className="options";

img.draggable= true;

img.ondragstart="dragStart_handler(event)";

divOptions.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(img);
```

And this is the html part:

```
<div id='options'> <!-- Here should be the divXX and the img --> </div>
```

I also used the methods addEventListener and attachEvent. But nothing seems to work. Can I write the div and the image to the HTML in another way?

Comment: Can you create a working example for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assignment is bad:

```
img.ondragstart="dragStart_handler(event)";
```

You're assigning a string to a property that expects a function.

This should work:

```
img.ondragstart = dragStart_handler;
```

This is better:

```
img.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart_handler); // note: no "on"
```

---

I think you're confusing the convenience syntax where you write a little bit of JavaScript in HTML, like:

```
<img ondragstart="dragStart_handler(event);" />
```

I think you can also pass a string into functions like `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout("dragStart_handle", 100);
```

This works because JavaScript expects a function and will `eval` the string argument.

I would avoid this sytnax.

Answer (score 0):

```
img.setAttribute("ondragstart", "dragStart_handler(event)");
```

Let me know if that works for you. Works for me whilst `img.ondragstart` does not.

Comment: The DOM API distguinishes between properties, attributes and event listeners. Some of these are magically linked, which should be a huge red flag. Since we're attaching an event listener use `img.addEventListener()`

Comment: @Halcyon Yes that would definitely be the best approach.